# How to write DB2 SELECT statement in unload job for delimiters

Tags: select, db2, mainframe, jcl

I have been over this... seems silly but couldnt figure out!

I wanna UNLOAD a table but with a delimiter '|' in between the fields. Here is the JCL used to unload the table:

```
//JS020    EXEC PGM=IKJEFT01,                     
//             DYNAMNBR=20                        
//*                                               
//SYSTSPRT DD  SYSOUT=*                           
//SYSPRINT DD  SYSOUT=*                           
//SYSUDUMP DD  SYSOUT=*                           
//SYSPUNCH DD  SYSOUT=*                           
//*                                               
//SYSTSIN  DD  *                                  
  DSN SYSTEM(XXXX)                                
  RUN PROGRAM(DSNTIAUL) PLAN(DSNTIAUL) PARM('SQL')
//*                                               
//SYSREC00 DD  DSN=TABLEA.UNLOAD.FILE,            
//             DISP=(NEW,CATLG,DELETE),           
//             UNIT=SYSDA,LRECL=80                
//SYSIN    DD  *                                  
  SELECT  COLUMN1                                 
         ,'|',COLUMN2                                 
         ,'|',COLUMN3                                 
         ,'|',COLUMN4                                 
         ,'|',COLUMN5                                 
  FROM   TABLEA                                   
  WITH UR;                                        
/*                                                
//*
```

Output yields

```
VALUEA..|VALUEB..|VALUEC..|VALUED..|VALUEE
VALUEA..|VALUEB..|VALUEC..|VALUED..|VALUEE
VALUEA..|VALUEB..|VALUEC..|VALUED..|VALUEE
VALUEA..|VALUEB..|VALUEC..|VALUED..|VALUEE
VALUEA..|VALUEB..|VALUEC..|VALUED..|VALUEE
```

But I wish to have like below

```
VALUEA|VALUEB|VALUEC|VALUED|VALUEE
VALUEA|VALUEB|VALUEC|VALUED|VALUEE
VALUEA|VALUEB|VALUEC|VALUED|VALUEE
VALUEA|VALUEB|VALUEC|VALUED|VALUEE
VALUEA|VALUEB|VALUEC|VALUED|VALUEE
```

I'm not able to figure our why that .. is preceeding the delimiter '|'. Any guesses what does that value mean? Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try changing your `SELECT` as follows:

```
SELECT  COLUMN1                                   
       ,CHAR('|'),COLUMN2   
       ,CHAR('|'),COLUMN3  
       ,CHAR('|'),COLUMN4  
       ,CHAR('|'),COLUMN5  
FROM   TABLEA  
WITH UR;
```

Placing the string constant `'|'` in your input creates a variable length
character string on output. Variable length character strings are
preceded by a 2 byte binary field giving the length of the string.
In your case that would be 01 (try viewing the output with HEX ON). 
Since the length is a binary integer value
it does not display as you were expecting.

The scalar function `CHAR` converts a variable
length character string into a fixed length character string, which
is what you were expecting.

**Note:** DSNTIAUL is different from SPUFI, which I suspect you are more familiar with.
DSNTIAUL does *not* convert selected data to character, SPUFI does. So, if you used
DSNTIAUL to select a column containing numeric data (eg. DECIMAL), it will be written
to your output file in binary. VARCHAR data will be written with a leading 2 byte
length field (as was the '|' character in your example). Columns defined as fixed
length character (eg. CHAR(5)) will be written as fixed length character strings (no
leading binary length field).

Comment: Thanks for your response and yes its a length written preceding the actual character. I tried to give a string and length of that string is written. Anyhow thanks for resolution!

Answer (score 1):

> SELECT  trim(COLUMN1)||
>            **'|'**||trim(COLUMN2)||
>            **'|'**||trim(COLUMN3)||
>            **'|'**||trim(COLUMN4)||
>            **'|'**||trim(COLUMN5)                                    FROM   TABLEA                                      WITH UR;

In the select statement U'll trim the output of every column and append '|' using concatenate operator.As a result of using trim there will be no spaces in between column and '|'.[For more Ref:IBM Manual On Trim](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_trim.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use CHAR function:

```
SELECT  CHAR(COLUMN1                                   
   ,CHAR('|'),COLUMN2   
   ,CHAR('|'),COLUMN3  
   ,CHAR('|'),COLUMN4  
   ,CHAR('|'),COLUMN5)
FROM TABLEA  
WITH UR;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 `**SELECT COLUMN1  || CAST('|' AS CHAR(1))
  || COLUMN2  || CAST('|' AS CHAR(1))
  || COLUMN3  || CAST('|' AS CHAR(1))
  || COLUMN4  || CAST('|' AS CHAR(1))
  || COLUMN5 
FROM TABLEA  
WITH UR;**
```